# Java - calcular diferencia de años - localdate

Tags: java, localdate

Tengo que calcular mediante `LocalDate` la diferencia de años.

El código que tengo planteado es el siguiente:

```
public void setAge(int birthyear){
        birthyear = getBirthyear();         
        LocalDate now = new LocalDate.now();
        int age = Period.between(birthyear, now).getYears();
}
```

Del método getBirthyear obtengo el año para calcular la diferencia. Es un valor entero.

`Period.between` espera una fecha completa.
Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

He probado también a definir la variable `birthyear` como `Year` en vez de `int`, pero tampoco se soluciona de esta forma. Además, la variable debe estar definida como `int`

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

El problema que tienes es un problema de concepto.

¿Qué significa la diferencia en años entre un día y un número de años? Pongamos que *birthyear* es 1976.

Si el día es relevante, no será la misma diferencia si consideras que 1976 significa 1/1/1976 o 31/12/1976. Tendrías que decidir qué significa "1976": ¿1 de enero? ¿31 de diciembre? ¿otro?. Luego calculas esa fecha específica y sacas la diferencia en años.

Si el día no es relevante, sacas el año actual y le restas *birthyear*.

Naturalmente, como tu función se llama *setAge*, el día normalmente será relevante, **y necesitas pasar una fecha específica**. De hecho no se entiende muy bien la función; si le pasas un entero a una funcion *setAge* yo esperaría que ese número **ya fuera el número de años calculado**; si quieres hacer un *setAge* que calcule en función de la fecha de nacimiento haz un *setAge(LocalDate)*.

Comment: el día no es relevante. Yo tengo un año, p.ej. 1976, definido como entero y quiero calcular los años entre esa fecha y hoy (el año en el que hoy ejecuto el programa) El valor que devuelvo, debe ser un entero también. ```LocalDate``` no trabaja con enteros, ni trabaja sólo con el año. El error lo conozco, pero no sé cómo puedo resolverlo usando LocalDate, que es como debo hacerlo. Gracias por tu explicación!

Comment: Pues es la segunda opción. Extrae el año de la fecha actual y resta los dos enteros.